# C++ Resetting system commands

Tags: c++, string, input, system, text-files

Code

```
while (dataFile)
    {
        getline(dataFile, input, '$');
        if (getenv("windir"))
        {
            cmd = "open -a 'Google Chrome' http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + input;
        }

        else
        {
            cmd = "open -a 'Safari' http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + input;
        }
        system(cmd.c_str());
        cmd.erase(cmd.find(input));
        cout << cmd;
    }
```

When ever there are more than one words on the .txt file it will only look up the first word and than it can't do the others. It says this in the output `sh: line 2: WORD: command not found`. How can I get it to reset the command so the other words will work?

Initialization of cmd and input is inside the main method.

```
 string cmd;
 string input;
```

This is how the text file would look like:

```
Word1
Word2
WordETC
```

Comment: Do you mean when you have more than one word on a line, or multiple lines with words?

Comment: @jmstoker Multiple lines. One word goes on each line otherwise the program doesn't work at all, since it was meant to read one word per line.

Comment: What is the type of `input`?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to see the declaration of `cmd`.

Comment: @jmstoker the input is a string. And cmd is too which they are both initialized inside of the main function.

Comment: Go to the url: www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/inception(this is ok for single word 'inception'). Just input two words directly in your browser's url and see the effect. Check how the url and search text box changes when you input two words. Url doesn't recognize the way when you input as normal string as it's syntax is different.

Comment: @user1502952 Yes that is true, however the issue I am having is not about having two words going into the url at once. It is that I am unable to have the system command be repeated properly and open up multiple tabs for the words.

Comment: Show some sample input.

Comment: Have you stepped thru this with the debugger? What is "cmd" when you execute "system"?

Comment: @mattbat131 try with **open -a** option, this hopefully will open new tabs everytime you run system command, if this is what you want

Comment: @mattbat131 Why are you delimiting on `$` and not `\n`?

Comment: @kfsone The first command is corrects. The next two commands are just the words.

Comment: @jmstoker Thank you! It was because of the $. I was using the $, because when I learned to recently read .txt files the guide used the $.

Comment: FYI: You may find it useful to use a tool like 'ideone' to break your problems down into components. Here is how I disproved that "cmd" was not being reset: http://ideone.com/WiXy9P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for the Safari path, I'm assuming in OSX or similar, but on Windows 7 the following code will open a new tab in Google chrome

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::ifstream dataFile("C:\\test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);

    string input;
    std::string cmd;

    // This path will depend on the operation system
    std::string googlePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";        

    while (dataFile)
    {
        getline(dataFile, input, '\n'); // use \n for endline

        if (getenv("windir"))
        {
            cmd = "cmd /C start \"" + googlePath + "\" http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + input + " --newtab";
        }

        else
        {
            cmd = "open -a 'Safari' http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + input;
        }
        system(cmd.c_str());
        cmd.erase(cmd.find(input));
        cout << cmd;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

test.txt

```
turtle\r\n
dove\r\n
shoulder
```

Comment: The tabs aren't an issue, it's just that when the program tries to run the command again with a different word it is unable to work. I feel that when it cycles through the loop again it doesn't reset the command properly and it just uses the word for the command.

Comment: Is this on windows or another OS?  The above code gets the proper command for Windows each time.

Comment: I'm using it on a mac. The reason I have the program check if the os is windows or not is because since I got parallels if I run this program and have it set on google chrome it opens up parallels which I don't always want to happen.